# NodeJS, from promise chaining to async/await chaining

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, chaining

With `NodeJS version 16.14.0` I'm trying to migrate from a `promise .then().catch` to a `async/await` management. 
The problem is that with the first method, I was able to chain multiple functions sequentially, with the same big object passed through each of it (with `return resolve(bigObject)` and each function taking as input the same `bigObject`). I was doing this because I'm able to manage micro-errors inside the data (so no catch involved), returning the user a full list of errors:

```
var commonData = {
    data1: ...
    data2: ...
    data3: ...
    data4: ...
    data5: ...
    data6: ...
};

return function1(commonData)
.then(function2)
.then(function3)
.then(function4)
.then(function5)
.then(function(result) {
    //Inside this .then, I'd have the "result" variable as result of the chain
})
.catch(error => { return reject(error); });
```

How can I do it with async await system? This is what I've tried so far:

```
var commonData = {
    data1: ...
    data2: ...
    data3: ...
    data4: ...
    data5: ...
    data6: ...
};

commonData = await function1(commonData);
commonData = await function2(commonData);
commonData = await function3(commonData);
commonData = await function4(commonData);
commonData = await function5(commonData);

//I was expecting to have inside "commonData" the same situation 
//as "result" in the chain above
```

Is there another way to chain functions with the same big object passed through that I'm missing?

EDIT: 
2 of the functions I'm using in this part...they are designed this way because they are being called in other parts of the file too, I couldn't use them locally

```
//function 1
async function function1(commonData) {
    try {
        var data1 = await models.data1.findAll({where: {Domain_ID: [13,15]}})
        data1.forEach(function(dat) {
            commonData.data1.push(dat.dataValues);
        });
        
        return commonData;
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
}

//function2
async function function2(commonData) {
    try {
        var data2 = await models.data2.findAll();
        data2.forEach(function(dat) {
            commonData.data2.push(dat.dataValues);
        });
        
        return commonData;
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to give some examples of the functions you have? What sort of thing might you have in, for instance, `function2`?

Comment: @OliverRadini added function1 and function2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have it (`commonData = await function1(commonData)`, etc.) is just fine. But if you don't want to do that, you could nest the calls:

```
const result = await function5(
    await function4(
        await function3(
            await function2(
                await function1(commonData)
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Or use a loop:

```
let result = commonData;
for (const fn of [function1, function2, function3, function4, function5]) {
    result = await fn(result);
}
```

Or you could keep using `then`. Although in general mixing `async`/`await` with explicit promise handlers via `.then`/`.catch` is confusing, there are some limited times where you might do it:

```
const result = await function1(commonData)
    .then(function2)
    .then(function3)
    .then(function4)
    .then(function5);
```

It works because `async` functions are just a way to consume and produce promises.

---

Or with the **very big caveat** that you know that the functions only modify the *state* of the object and don't return (fulfill their promise with) a *different* object, you could do:

```
await function1(commonData);
await function2(commonData);
await function3(commonData);
await function4(commonData);
const result = await function5(commonData);
```

but it's a big caveat.

Comment: Nesting calls like that is more confusing than promises chaining to be honest. The loop is confusing too....I think i would stick with the chaining when i need that, and use async/await in every other cases...they can live together as much as i understand

Comment: @alesssz - I agree about the nesting, just pointing out alternatives to what you've already identified; your initial way of doing it is the simple, straightfoward way as I said at the top of the answer. (I also find the loop clear, but if you don't, you don't. :-) )

Comment: can you explain the loop then please? The fact `result` is used for `commonData` and then inside the loop with `result = await fn(result)` is a bit confusing to me...or maybe is the same thing but presented in a different way

Comment: @alesssz - We start out setting `result` to `commonData`, then we enter the loop. On the first loop iteration, `fn` is `function1`, so `result = await fn(result)` is `result = await function1(result)`. This is exactly like your original `commonData = await function1(commonData)` just using a different variable name (we could use `commonData` if you don't need it to be called `result`). On the second loop iteration `fn` is `function2`, and we do the same thing again, but calling `function2`. And so on. I used `result` instead of `commonData`...

Comment: ...because in the normal case, an async function doesn't fulfill its promise with the same object it receives, so calling it `commonData` when that could be something different after the first call would be misleading. With your **specific** functions, it would be fine, but not generally.

Comment: *(Damnit, missed out my `await`s in that comment explaining the loops. I've fixed it.)*

Comment: @alesssz - `result` will only be `undefined` at the end of the loop if `function5` fulfills its promise with `undefined` (perhaps by having no `return` at all).

Answer (score 1):

No, there´s no other way.
One of the reasons why Async/Await was implemented is that Promise chaining can look pretty ugly and messy. If you prefer `.then()`, just stick with it in this module.

For further reading: https://blog.logrocket.com/promise-chaining-is-dead-long-live-async-await-445897870abc/

Comment: Oh I see...so for functions I'm using in this part, I should use `.then()` and for the other parts that do not require chaining, I can use `async/await`, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you dont have to migrate everything to async/await.
They both work with the same underlying concept. (Promises)